# What is a Hyper-Category?

Tags: category-theory

I am reading the 2008 book ["Institution Independent Model Theory"](https://books.google.de/books?id=aEpn60-EDXwC) by Razvan Diaconescu and looking up what the category ℂat was it states in the symbol Index

> ℂat: the hyper-category of categories as objects and functors as arrows

But it nowhere defines what a hyper-category is. Is this just a way of saying that it is a Category containing Categories?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's analogous to the idea of a "hyper-*class*," which is to classes what classes are to sets. Basically, in an appropriate background theory, a hypercategory consists of a *hyperclass* of objects and a *hyperclass* of morphisms, as opposed to a class of objects and a class of morphisms (= category) or a set of objects and a set of morphisms (= small category).

Note that to even talk about such things, we need to enrich our background set theory in a manner similar to how we move from ZFC to [NBG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann%E2%80%93Bernays%E2%80%93G%C3%B6del_set_theory). However, we can do this in a "conservative way," so this isn't as big a deal as it sounds.

Comment: A so essentially it's very big. :-)

Comment: @HenryStory Yup. And the "category" of hypercategories will be a hyperhypercategory, and etc.

Comment: Your answer fits with what the author of the book writes in a more recent 2015 article in Internet Encyclopedia of Philosophy on Institution Theory, which being philosophical, explains some of the basics a lot better than the book. He writes "The Σ-models may be so many that they may not constitute a set anymore. In examples this is closely related to the fact that there does not exists ‘the set of all sets’, which would be a violation of one of the axioms of formal set theory." https://www.iep.utm.edu/insti-th/